# Generating random values from a multivariate skew-normal with fixed marginals

Tags: r, random-generation, skew-normal-distribution

I'm generating random values from the multivariate skew-normal, and I want that the marginal distributions from this multivariate one have fixed parameters as the following:

I'm generating from multivariate skew-normal: $X=SN_2\left(\mu=(0,0),\Sigma=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{.5}\\
{.5}&1
\end{array}} \right], \lambda=(.9,.9) \right)$,

in the univariate case I have:

$Y=SN_1(\mu=0, \sigma^2=1,\lambda=.9)$

Then, if I generate a lot of values from this distributions I expect to have the same empirical distribution, in $R$, I would have the graphics very similar from:

```
> plot(density(X[1,]))
> plot(density(Y))
```

where $X$ is a matrix 2x2.

But it's not what I'm getting.

Bellow are my "real code"

```
> library(sn)
> a <- c(1,.5)
> b <- c(.5,1)
> ma=matrix(c(a,b),ncol = 2, byrow = F)
> op <- list(xi=rep(0,2), Psi=ma, lambda=rep(6.297913,2))
> YN<- rmsn(1, dp=op2dp(op,"SN"))[1,]
> 
> SN = replicate(100000,expr = rmsn(1, dp=op2dp(op,"SN"))[1,])
> 
> plot(density(SN[1,]))
> curve(dsn(x,dp=c(0,1,6.297913)),col=3,add=T)
```

[image]

This curves is suppose to be equal, right? What can I do to generate multivariate skew normal with fixed parameters for the skew-normal marginals distributions?

Answer (score 1):

The multivariate skew normal does not have skew normal marginals. This is a well known unpleasant feature of this distribution.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337278

Only some specific versions of the skew normal have skew normal marginals.

https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2093

If you want to easily generate a bivariate distribution with skew normal marginals, then you can use a copula with skew normal marginals. This sort of models have already been studied in the statistical literature.